# Can't connect MySQL server using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, server, xampp, archlinux

I downloaded XAMPP from the official website and did the manual installation of the .run file, but only apache server and ProFTPD have the "running" status, the MySQL server remains "stopped".

This appears on terminal when I run `./xampp start` command:

```
[socrates lampp]# ./xampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.2.0-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
OK.
[socrates lampp]# /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (28954) - Nonexistent process
```

Someone knows why is it happening and how can I solve it?

I already tried to reinstall using AUR and again the official website executablem but the problem still appears.

I'm using Manjaro Linux 22.0 (Archlinux based distro).

Comment: Try to not enter in sudo mode for security reasons. Now if you're ouf of sudo mode, maybe it can work if you try `sudo service stop mysql`, check if it stopped with `sudo service stop mysql`  now try to run it again with `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: @RaulPenate I tried `sudo service stop mysql`  but shows on terminal `sudo: service: command not found`

Comment: Oops, I've realized that you're using an arch-based distro, try with  `sudo systemctl stop mysql` and `sudo systemctl status mysql`